# RegionPlot to plot a quarter circle

Tags: plotting, regions

How do you use the `RegionPlot` command to plot a quarter circle at the origin with a radius of 4 that is in the first quadrant?

Answer (score 3):

- If the `quarter circle` means the region of disk.

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 4^2, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

- If the `quarter circle` means only the circumference.

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 4^2, {{x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}}], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Blue, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

- If the `quarter circle` means the boundary of disk.

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 4^2, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Blue, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: `Show[RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 4^2, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}], 
 PlotRange -> 4]`

Answer (score 2):

You could start with a Disk primitive:

```
Disk[{0, 0}, 4, {0, Pi/2}]
```

With that you can simply wrap with Graphics to get a visualization:

```
Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 4, {0, Pi/2}]]
```

[image]

RegionPlot also works if you do need that specific form:

```
RegionPlot[Disk[{0, 0}, 4, {0, Pi/2}]]
```

[image]

Most of the graphics primitives work as regions, so you can also do stuff like this:

```
DiscretizeRegion[Disk[{0, 0}, 4, {0, Pi/2}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use ImplicitRegion to define the quarter circle like:

```
circ4 = ImplicitRegion[{x >= 0, y >= 0, x^2 + y^2 <= 16}, {x, y}]
```

You can then plot it like:

```
RegionPlot[circ4]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
RegionPlot[Norm[{x, y}] < 4 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

---

Also try:

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[Norm[{x, y}, p] < 4
  , {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
 , {{p, 2}, 1, 6}
 ]
```